# Can I get my gold badge revoked?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, badges, revoked-badges

I asked the extremely popular question: [Do most web 'programmers' (not designers) use wysiwyg editors or hand code their HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406052/do-most-web-programmers-not-designers-use-wysiwyg-editors-or-hand-code-their)

When I asked it, I intended it to be a poll type of question (yeah yeah, I know, no polls), anyway, I added a 'Yes' & 'No' answer expecting people to vote them up & down.

The Yes answer received enough votes to earn me a gold badge.

This was unintended, and I've felt a little guilty about this for a long time.

Could I have that badge revoked?

For more details, see [the question comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406052/do-most-web-programmers-not-designers-use-wysiwyg-editors-or-hand-code-their).

**EDIT**: Just to let you know, I emailed as suggested in the accepted answer, and was told that the whole question would need to be deleted, and if I was ok with that.  I told them no, since it's obviously been a pretty popular question.

Thanks for the advice, I guess I'll just live with my undeserved gold badge.  ;-)  ... life is rough.

Comment: Don't feel guilty. Those are earned upvotes. Maybe easy votes but sometimes you take a lot of work for an answer only to get a single upvote.

Comment: Don't feel guilty. It's the stackoverflow users that are crazily vote-happy, not your fault for indulging them. If it makes you feel better, I downvoted the question, because I think polls are worse than worthless. ;)

Comment: thanks for the update. Congratulations... I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can theoretically e-mail team@stackoverflow.com. I know they can remove badges that you earned and then unearned (although they prefer not to), but I don't know if it's possible to eliminate a badge you still technically deserve, I would expect the badge awarding script to just give it to you again. Either way, I think you'll need to e-mail the team directly though

Answer (score 5):

Unless you take @Michael's route and the team makes an extra-special exception for you, the answer is no. It's well-documented that badges are never revoked unless the requirements change, which doesn't apply here, or you commit gross cheating, which means cracking their network and attacking their database, not posting a poll answer.

Getting rid of things that you've earned for any reason doesn't seem to be popular 'round these parts, as I found out with [one of my first questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45789/voluntarily-discard-reputation). I upvoted you for a good question, though.