# Is there any way to reduce reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

I don't like having a lot of reputation. I like staying under 100 reputation.

Is there any feasible way to do that, like:

1. Donating some reputation
2. Using bounties
3. By $$$$

Comment: -1, ask bad questions? give bad answers?

Comment: Mark all answers as Community Wiki

Comment: @six i don't want to trouble users with bad QA , i want the right way to do that

Comment: @JNK If we don't ask questions HOW will other answer them :)

Comment: What about a low reputation attracts you?

Comment: @rick - If I had to guess, based on his pattern of behavior, the lack of responsibility.  If he just asks a ton of questions and keeps his rep low all he has to do is let people solve his problems for him.

Comment: @JNK This site is for solving problems of others , whats harm in that. I am not getting answers at gunpoint. Frankly speaking I like low rep because then i don't have to worry if someone give the -ve vote and why i get less upvotes . I remember my previous account closed at 3000rep due to bad arguments with senior member and some bad questions. Although questions were not that bad but as he was senior with very high rep , everyone thinks he true and they suspended me. Then i thought i won't let my rep go up so that i don't need to worry bout rep and just concentrate of questions

Comment: You could always ask a question likely to attract a lot of downvotes. Well, you already know all about that.

Comment: Also, "senior" members do not have the power to suspend anyone. Only moderators can do that, and they'll only do it for exceptional cases. You're seriously misunderstanding the reputation system, and trying to solve a non-existent problem using an inappropriate method. Just so you know...

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45789/voluntarily-discard-reputation

Comment: Looks like he found out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need [75 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties) to offer bounties, so #2 certainly works